# sid not returned by cfprocparam that is connected to oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

The application in question runs on `Coldfusion 11` with `hotfix 7` and running on a `Linux` server that is connected to a `Windows Oracle database`. The goal is to make the application run on `Linux` which is a step by step process (which is why the database in on `Windows server`).

I know the database works because it connects successfully via the `Coldfusion` administrator panel and this `SQL` statement returns an `user_id` successfully:

```
<cfquery name="qUser" datasource="#Application.datasource#">
    SELECT td_user_id
        FROM td_user
        WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
</cfquery>
```

The code in question is such:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="td_session_pkg.new_session" datasource="#application.datasource#">
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CHAR" value="#arguments.username#">
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CHAR" value="#arguments.password#">
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CHAR" value="#cgi.remote_addr#">
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#rand_int#">
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#application.app_id#">
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="1">
    <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#pwdRequired#">
    <cfprocparam type="Out" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_CHAR" variable="sid">
</cfstoredproc>

<!--- Test --->
<cfquery name="testS" datasource="#Application.datasource#">
        SELECT
            sys_context('USERENV','SID') AS theSid
            FROM dual
</cfquery>
<cfthrow message="SID: #sid# and #testS.theSid#">
```

The `cfthrow` returns

> SID: (blank here) and 37

I've had tried many things but have yet to return the `sid` correctly (it is needed to continue user authentication). The values inside the `cfprocparam` tags are variables stated above and all have valid values.

- Coldfusion variables are **not** case sensitive, as stated by Adobe

Any insight as to why this wouldn't return the `sid` and why the `SQL` statement would? (from my research I believe they are the same thing).

Thanks for the help, I am will and answer any questions quickly.

Comment: Start with is the procedure executing correctly if you pass the same parameters inside Oracle? Using SQL/Plus or SQL Developer, can you connect to the DB and run something like `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON; DECLARE sid VARCHAR2(20); BEGIN td_session_pkg.new_session( 'username', 'password', 'remote_addr', 0, 0, 1, 0, sid ); DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'SID' || sid ); END; /` (with appropriate values). Test that the function does what you expect an its not a problem with the procedure.

Comment: I just ran that, did a test query and its connected. Then tried the code you provided with substituted values and got: `Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 35:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SID' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the code I posted in comments has the white-space mangled:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  sid VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  td_session_pkg.new_session(
    'username',
    'password',
    'remote_addr',
    0,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    sid
  );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'SID' || sid );
END;
/
```

Run this in an SQL client (i.e. SQL developer or SQL/Plus) from the user you would connect to via ColdFusion.

The aim is to test that the database:

1. Has the procedure.
2. The database user has access to it.
3. The procedure runs in the database.
4. The procedure gives the expected result.

Running the query successfully will tell you that #1-#3 are fine and you can check #4 against your expectations.

If any aren't as expected then you know the problem is at the database end and not in ColdFusion.

If they run as expected then you can start looking at the CF settings to make sure your datasources are pointing where you expect (i.e. are they connecting to the correct user) and that the datasource has permissions to execute procedures.

Then if that is all correct, look at the variables you are passing into the `<CFSTOREDPROC>` and `<CFPROCPARAM>` tags - are the datasource and variables as expected.

If you want to formalize it as you go then you could write unit & integration tests which cover the steps you try and next time you want to test things you just run the test suites.

Comment: I switched sid to the first parameter and it worked in SQL Developer. Then did the same in Coldfusion and it finally worked, no idea why now and not before. Thanks for all the help.